# post ajax when item on index page clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index page, where a user can activate one item at a time. When a user clicks the activate button I want to do something to the item. My predicament is how do I identify which item was clicked on the page. Is there a way I can have 1 javascript function that could be used to handle any of the items clicked on?

html:

```
<ul>
  <li> item 1 </li>  
  <li> item 2 </li>  
  <li> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
  $('.li').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/activate,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        item: { id: 1 }
      },
      success: function(data){
        alert("you did it")
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: `this` within any event handler is element that event occurred on. What is your objective?

Comment: The selector is wrong. Your JS object is invalid. You are missing quotes and semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon the other comments, once the other errors are fixed (such as your selector, the lack of semicolons, etc), you can use the `this` variable to retrieve the information you're looking for. In addition, you can add an id to each li element so you know which one you're looking at. For example:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="li1"> item 1 </li>  
  <li id="li2"> item 2 </li>  
  <li id="li3"> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select the `<li>` element, in the jQuery change `.li` to `li`(just remove the dot).

You only use to dot "." when you're selecting a class ("#" for selecting an id). So basically you've been selecting a class called li instead of the element `<li>`

Once you select the element you want, inside the jQuery selector you can use `$(this)` to refer to the same element that was clicked.

eg:

Changethe color

```js
$("li").click(function(){

  //Button was clicked
  $(this).css("color", "#ff0000"); // Change color of clicked li
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter `event` passed to your function that handle the click. From that you can find the target element:

```
$('.li').click(function(event) {
   var target = event.target;
   ....
});
```

Another way is `this` indicator:

```
$('.li').click(function() {
 $(this).text();
});
```